# code coverage for junit plug-in tests with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, jacoco

Below is my maste pom file profile for my product unit tests. we have junit plug-in tests.
These pom file configurations not giving me the jacoco code coverage file(.exec) in any location. 
please help me if any wrong some where. Thank you

```xml
    <profile>
        <id>unit-tests</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../../../test/com.xxxx.tools.comms.test.utilities</module>

            <!-- product related unit tests 
            <module>../../../test/com.xxxx.comms.product.test</module>
            <module>../../../test/com.xxxx.comms.product.mas.test</module>-->
            <module>../../../test/com.xxxx.comms.product.iv.test</module> 
        </modules>

        <properties>
            <!-- Properties to enable jacoco code coverage analysis -->
            <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Where to put jacoco coverage report -->
                        <destFile>C:/Userdata/product/GIT/Team/coverage/product1/jacoco/12.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>

                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>


<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Use of Tycho -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Tests*.java,**/*Tests.java,**/*TestCase.java,**/Test*.java,**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                    <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
                    <!-- Kill test JVM if tests take more than 1 minute to finish -->
                    <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>600</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <!-- Configuration of target platforms -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- workaround for TYCHO-349 or TYCHO-313 -->
                        <strictVersions>false</strictVersions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: What is your surefire configuration? You have to configure surefire to fork in order to enable the jacoco agent.

Comment: please find my plugin configuration added above. But i see that by default the fork is true and forkCount=1

Comment: The main culprit is using the tycho-surefire pugin I think. There is some info about this on the net, but it seems to always be a lot of fiddling. You could have a look at these: https://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/jacoco-tycho-and-coverage-reports/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944223/how-do-i-make-jenkins-sonar-and-the-jacoco-plugin-work-together-for-eclipse-tyc, http://mdwhatever.free.fr/index.php/2011/09/quality-analysis-on-eclipse-plugins-with-tycho-sonar-jacoco-and-swtbot/, https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/tycho

Comment: hi spacetrucker,

I got the problem source. the culprit is <argLine> parameter in tycho-surefire-plugin configuration.
If this param is present, jacoco file is not generated. I removed it and now .exec file is generated.

More info found at
http://tycho-user.eclipse.narkive.com/Ox87F4kB/tycho-surefire-argline-causes-no-jacaco-exec

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @AshokK, thanks for telling us how you solved the problem.  I suggest that you make your comment into an answer and then mark it as an accepted answer so it can help other StackOverflow users who have the same issue now or in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem source.
The culprit is `<argLine>` parameter in **tycho-surefire-plugin** configuration.
If this param is present, jacoco file is not generated. I removed it and now .exec file is generated.
More info found at [tycho-surefire argLine causes no jacaco.exec](http://tycho-user.eclipse.narkive.com/Ox87F4kB/tycho-surefire-argline-causes-no-jacaco-exec)